VSCode C++ Extension cannot locate "physics::ModelPtr" from gazebo library
I am trying to use VSCode to write ROS program. However, the C++ Extension seems to have trouble finding the physics::ModelPtr. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Here is my code:
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>

namespace gazebo
{
  class camera_pose_control : public ModelPlugin
  {
    private: physics::ModelPtr model;
    private: ros::NodeHandle nh;
    private: ros::Subscriber poseSub;

    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
      std::cout << "Loading Camera Pose Control Plugin\n" << std::endl;
      this->model = _model;

      // ROS Node and Subscriber
      int argc = 0;
      char **argv = NULL;
      ros::init(argc, argv, "gazebo_client", ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
      ROS_INFO("ROS node initialized within Gazebo Plugin");
      poseSub = nh.subscribe("camera/pose", 10, &camera_pose_control::OnPoseReceived, this);
    }

    // Callback function to set the model pose
    public: void OnPoseReceived(const geometry_msgs::PoseConstPtr &msg)
    {
      ignition::math::Pose3d newPose(msg->position.x, msg->position.y, msg->position.z,
                                     msg->orientation.w, msg->orientation.x, msg->orientation.y, msg->orientation.z);
      this->model->SetWorldPose(newPose);
    }
  };
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(camera_pose_control)
}

Here is my c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "browse": {
                "databaseFilename": "${default}",
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
            },
            "includePath": [
                "/opt/ros/noetic/include/**",
                "/root/ml_project_ws/src/ml_project/include/**",
                "/usr/include/**",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/**"
            ],
            "name": "ROS",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}


Is this a problem detected by intellisense or the compiler? With VS Code it's easy to specify an include folder to one of the two without the other.

@user4581301 intellisense!! I can compile without any problem.

Groovy. 's what I suspected because you included the right file for it, but I had to be sure. Too many folk get the files mixed up or don't know they have to edit two files.

I know next-to-nothing about VS Code's intrellisence, so the only suggestion I can make is to make sure you don't need /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/include/ instead of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/.

Are you really supposed to put your stuff in namespace gazebo? It's not uncommon for libraries to allow extensions to their namespace but it's also often a mistake by users when it's not intended to be extended.

@user4581301 I have try both /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/include/** and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/**, but the result is still the same. How do I make sure I have included the right file? Are you saying there might be two physics.hh?

@TedLyngmo I have remove the namespace and add it to every variable (gazebo::physics::ModelPtr), but the result is still the same.

Long-standing convention is to put a library's export headers in an "include" directory. I just wanted to make sure you'd tried all of the low-hanging fruit before you spent any more time than you already have. Since you know where the file is, open it up and make sure ModelPtr is in there (or in a file included by physics.hh, and you've reported you can compile, so it sure as fud better be) and not walled off by conditional compilation or some other nasty you'll have to resolve so that intellisense can see the definition.

@user4581301 I have checked that ModelPtr is defined in PhysicsTypes.hh. And PhysicsTypes.hh is included by physics.hh. But somehow the intellisense could not find the definition in PhysicsTypes.hh? I think this might be the problem.

@user4581301 But the error message changes to incomplete type "gazebo::physics::ModelPtr" (aka "boost::shared_ptr<gazebo::physics::Model>") is not allowed

I've had the same problem and has been rather frustrating but I've managed to fix it on my machine. Hopefully this will work for others.
Go to your C++ Configurations and change the C++ standard to at least C++17. After changing this, intellisense started working and I could locate all files.
TLDR Change C++ standard to C++17

Hey it does wipe out most of the errors!! Thanks a lot! However, I still have this two error. Do you have any idea how to fix these?
Line 14 "gazebo::sdf::ElementPtr" : name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace nameC/C++(276)
Line 35 "GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN": object of abstract class type "camera_pose_control" is not allowed:C/C++(322)
